# Why the moduleId in Artifactory for an Artifact ends with 'unspecified'?

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I have a multi-sub-project and is using Gradle Artifactory plugin to publish artifacts. But under 'Builds' section, the ModuleId is ending with 'unspecified'. Probably its the version. Which parameter controls it for the plugin, or how do I specify the ModuleId to use? I see the version correctly in the jar which I am publishing.

I looked here but didn't find anything useful in this context: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin

Comment: Have you got answer for this?